# How to keep Network Manager from creating multiple named networks for the same actual network?

Tags: wireless, networking

Network Manager is connecting to the same network but keeps creating different "profiles" like thomson, thomson1, thomson 2.

How can I fix this, so it always shows and connects to the same network by the same name?

Output of `lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e59] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8723]
```

Output of `nm-tool`:

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [INFINITUM440C] -----------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8723ae
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        C0:D9:62:47:E1:AD

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           72 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    INFINITUM4813:   Infra, 10:47:80:15:B6:51, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
    *INFINITUM440C:  Infra, E0:24:7F:38:06:4D, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 83 WPA WPA2
    corpen:          Infra, 00:60:B3:44:F5:D3, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 18 WEP
    INFINITUMCA0C:   Infra, E0:24:7F:37:F8:D3, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40 WPA WPA2
    INFINITUM4D0D:   Infra, 00:46:4B:C9:2B:56, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 26 WPA WPA2
    INFINITUMC413:   Infra, 10:47:80:15:9E:CD, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA WPA2
    FaciNet15:       Infra, 00:15:6D:67:39:10, Freq 2427 MHz, Rate 11 Mb/s, Strength 100

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.50
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.254

    DNS:             8.8.8.8
    DNS:             8.8.4.4


- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            alx
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:8C:FA:40:7E:4A

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

Comment: Is there something "wrong" with this? I've seen Windows do this too... It's never caused any problems.

Comment: Absolutely, my settings change everytime and it is frustating to add my IP again so my port forwarding rules can match.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Do you know what network card you have? (should be in the output of `lspci -nn`)

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question and include more details, like what Seth mentions, the output of `nm-tool`.

Comment: I really need more help.

Comment: Does your wlan number increment too?  I see that behavior on a Toshiba (same alx/rtl8723ae driver) U 13.04.   Assumed some udev rule was whacked, but caused me no problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you have DHCP set up on your router, your device could be pulling a new IP address each time you connect, requiring a new sign in. I would try going into your routers settings, set up a static IP address to your computer, reset your computer and then re-connect and see what it does. If it does the same thing then there may be a software issue with the OS, if not then it may be an issue with your network configuration.